# JqueryMobile scroll not working in webview (Android 2.3)

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile, webview

I've created a webapp using jquery Mobile and I'm rendering it on a native app via a webview. It works nicely with Android 4+ devices, but using a Gingerbread device the scroll simply doesn't work.

Loading the website directly on the device's browser does work, it's just on the webview of my app. This is how I create the webview:

```
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebView.setFocusable(true);
    mWebView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    WebSettings s = mWebView.getSettings();
    // s.setUserAgentString(Constants.USER_AGENT);
    s.setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    s.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    s.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    s.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    s.setSupportZoom(true);

    s.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    s.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    s.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    s.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    s.setSavePassword(true);
    s.setSaveFormData(true);
    s.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Any suggestions on where the problem could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because of the CSS property `overflow:hidden` being set on the `body` by jQuery Mobile. I set it to auto for my pre Honeycomb devices and seems to be working okay.

In case anyone is interested, here's what I did using jQuery:

```
function isAndroidBelow3() {
    return !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Android [1-2]/i);
}

if(isAndroidBelow3()){
    $(document.body).css("overflow", "auto");
}
```